# error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers [1] - IBAction

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch

Ever since I've upgraded to Xcode 4. I've got this error and i can't seem to figure out whats wrong.

error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers [1]

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

    @interface SixViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {

        IBOutlet UIImageView *play;
        AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;
        float progress;
        NSTimer *timer;
        IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressView;
        int mainInt;
        IBAction *timeOut;
    }
```

It highlights the error on ibaction line

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IBAction` is intended as a return value for methods:

```
- (IBAction)someMethod;
```

... to tell Interface Builder that it is available for target/action connections. It is not intended as a variable data type, although you can get away with it when `IBAction` is defined as `void`.

However, you should use the correct data type for this variable, e.g. `id` for generic objects or maybe `NSTimeInterval` depending on what you're actually trying to do here.